# Yii: User Auth not working

Tags: php, yii

SO I try to login to an app in Yii, it seems to stop at their the validate or the login function of my site controller. It never logs in it never does anything useful. Nothing displays, no error, nada zip

I was following: http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/04/simple-authentication-with-the-yii-framework/

UserIdentity class:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity

public function authenticate()
{

        $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        $saltedPW = ""; // null string for salted PW

        if ($user===null) { // No user found!
                $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        }

        if ($user!==null){
            // salt the user password string then hash
            // incase $user pw is not a salted hash, rather a password string
            $saltedPW = md5(Yii::app()->params["salt"] . $user->password);

            //testing the password 
            if (($user->password !== $this->password) || 
                ($saltedPW       !== $this->password))
            {
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            } 
            else 
            {
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            }
        }
    return !$this->errorCode;
    }
```

}

login from site controller:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
                    {
                        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model)); 
                    }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Login form

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe;
    private $_identity;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * The rules state that username and password are required,
     * and password needs to be authenticated.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // username and password are required
            array('username, password', 'required'),
            // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
            array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
            // password needs to be authenticated
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'rememberMe'=>'Remember me next time',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates the password.
     * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
     */
    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())
        {
            $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
            if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
                $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
     * @return boolean whether login is successful
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->_identity===null)
        {
            $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
            $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
        if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
        {
            $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
            Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Seeing the view code could help - it might be missing the logic to print errors, or the input fields might be misnamed... 2) The way you're validating the passwords is a mess. As I  see, you are expecting the user record in the DB to contain the plain text password and will accept it if the user types in the same plain text or its salted version? You should be going the other way around - db contains hash and salt for each user, login routine hashes the entered password with the user's salt, `strcmp` the two hashes. 3) Get [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), decent debugging is very helpful.

Comment: From my experience, if nothing (quote: "Nothing displays, no error, nada zip") appears in the browser window, the cause is often a PHP error. Did you have a look at the webserver error log?

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced the UserIdentity Class with this and its working.

protected/components/UserIdentity.php

```
<?php

/**
 * UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
 * It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
 * data can identity the user.
 */
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

    /**
     * Id for current user.
     * @var type 
     */
    private $_id;

    /**
     * Email address variable.
     * @var type 
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * Custom error indicators.
     */

    const ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID = 3;
    const ERROR_ACCOUNT_INACTIVE = 4;

    /**
     * Over-ride the parent constructor and uses email for auth.
     * @param type $email
     * @param type $password
     */
    public function __construct($email, $password) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->username = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function authenticate() {
        // we need to filter on email only
        $attrs = array('email' => $this->email);
        // obtain all users matching this criterion
        $record = User::model()->findByAttributes($attrs);
        // if no users are obtained, we need to set custom message.
        if ($record === null)
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID;
        // if password does not match, indicate this via message.
        else if ($record->password !== crypt($this->password, $record->password))
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        // check if user account is enabled.
        else if ($record->is_authorised == 0)
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_ACCOUNT_INACTIVE;
        else {
            // all check passed, now initiate a whatevr.
            $this->_id = $record->id;
            $this->email = $this->username = $record->email;
            // no error occurred.
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        // return the errorCode.
        return $this->errorCode;
    }

    /**
     * Returns ID.
     * @return type
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns username, part before '@' sign.
     * @return type
     */
    public function getName() {
        $usernameParts = explode('@', $this->email);
        return $usernameParts[0];
    }

}
```